# MySQL Top10 for 7 Days Ago

Tags: mysql, days

I have a problem...
I search in this site for any solutions... I tried them but on one workout :(
So I'm trying to get the top 10 results for 7 days ago by views...
So I try codes like that:

```
SELECT * FROM `data` 
WHERE cast(`date` as DATE) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
AND CURDATE() ORDER by `viewed` DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `data` 
WHERE `date` > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
ORDER by `viewed` DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `data` 
WHERE DATE(`date`) = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7) 
ORDER by `viewed` DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM `data` 
WHERE `date` >= SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
ORDER by `viewed` DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

I try them with any combination with `NOW()` `TIME()` `DATE()` `CURDATE()` `SUBDATE()` `SUBTIME()` `DATE_SUB()` etc... but nothing works :( I really don't know what is the problem. I submit the date to database with `time()` function(PHP) can it be that the problem?

Comment: You submit the date into mysql with the `time()` function in _PHP_ or MySQL's own [`TIME()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time)? What is the data type of your `date` column? If you are populating it with PHP `time()`, it may be a unix timestamp

Comment: What does "nothing works" mean?  Can you show some sample data?

Comment: What is the data type of date?

Comment: Its php time(). It save it into `data` like "1392749561"

Comment: With type I mean the type in your database.

Comment: @Nicox could you please display a time like its save in you database. Give 5 examples for instance.

Comment: I note it above but here: 1392749561, 1392749950, 1392850985, 1393023471, 1392936840

Comment: @Nicox thanks working on a example.

Comment: @Nicox have you tried my answer below?

Comment: @Nicox you're welcome. Success with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT date, viewed FROM data
WHERE date BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 day) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
ORDER BY viewed DESC
LIMIT 0,10;
```

And this if you want the date and time displayed.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(date), viewed FROM data
WHERE date BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 day) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
ORDER BY viewed DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE data 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     date varchar(10),
     viewed int
    );

INSERT INTO data
(date, viewed)
VALUES
(1392749561, 50),
(1392749950, 25),
(1392850985, 10),
(1393023471, 75),
(1392936840, 100);
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cec69/1)